# Docking a WinForm inside another WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm stuck at a problem and the old answers regarding the same problem are not quite recent enough so i thought it'd be okay to ask again.
My question is: How can i dock one form inside another form? Would it be more appropriate to use a Panel and a Form instead? Is the first option even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx

Comment: I've tried that already and unfortunately i can't get the idea out of it. Would you mind telling me your idea?

Comment: The point is that you should be using a UserControl for this (docking inside of another Form), not a Form.

Comment: @CodyGray I require a form to do so, i'm aware of the fact that a UserControl would've been cleaner and less messy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create 2 forms, Form1 and Form2. Set TopLevel property of Form2 to false. In form load for Form1 add code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();

    this.Controls.Add(frm2);
}
```

This will include form2 in form1, you then have to set properties on form2 if you want to remove the title bar to make the form more like a Panel.

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick perfectly! Now i only have to dock it at a precise position.

Comment: Indeed. It strains the imagination why you wouldn't just use a Panel or a UserControl, though. (Also, TopLevel is set to false by default. It is exceptionally rare that it should *ever* be set to true.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have some reusable panel that may be used on forms I think User Control will be what you are looking for.